# loop for insertion in linked list not working

Tags: c, linked-list, singly-linked-list, insertion, function-definition

I'm trying to insert some nodes at the end of the linked list but something is not right in this code.

Here I'm trying to make a loop and with the help of this loop I want the user to enter all numbers for the list but I guess I'm missing something.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct node{
int data;
struct node* next;

           };
void insert(struct node** ref)
 {   int n,i=0 ;

 printf("how many numers:\n");
scanf("%d",&n);
fflush(stdin);
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    struct node* temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    struct node* last = *ref;
    printf("enter the number:\n");
    scanf("%d",&(temp->data));
    fflush(stdin);
    temp->next = NULL;
    if(*ref==NULL)
       {
        *ref = temp;
        return;
       }
    while(last->next != NULL)
        last = last->next;

    last->next = temp;

}
  return;
  }

int main()
 {
   struct node* head=NULL;
   insert(&head);
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When the function is called for an empty list then it inserts only one element in the list and exits.

```
if(*ref==NULL)
   {
    *ref = temp;
    return;
   }
```

Also pay attention to that calling `fflush` for `stdin` has undefined behavior.

```
fflush(stdin);
```

The function can be defined the following way

```
size_t insert( struct node **ref )
{
    printf( "how many numbers: " );

    size_t n = 0;
    scanf( "%zu", &n );

    if ( n != 0 )
    {
        while ( *ref != NULL )
        {
            ref = &( *ref )->next;
        }
    }

    size_t i = 0;

    for ( ; i < n && ( *ref = malloc( sizeof( struct node ) ) ) != NULL; i++ )
    {
        ( *ref )->data = 0;
        ( *ref )->next = NULL;        

        printf( "enter the number: " );
        scanf( "%d", &( *ref )->data );

        ref = &( *ref )->next;
    }

    return i;
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node* next;
};

size_t insert( struct node **ref )
{
    printf( "how many numbers: " );

    size_t n = 0;
    scanf( "%zu", &n );

    if ( n != 0 )
    {
        while ( *ref != NULL )
        {
            ref = &( *ref )->next;
        }
    }

    size_t i = 0;

    for ( ; i < n && ( *ref = malloc( sizeof( struct node ) ) ) != NULL; i++ )
    {
        ( *ref )->data = 0;
        ( *ref )->next = NULL;        

        printf( "enter the number: " );
        scanf( "%d", &( *ref )->data );

        ref = &( *ref )->next;
    }

    return i;
}

void display( struct node *head )
{
    for ( ; head != NULL; head= head->next )
    {
        printf( "%d -> ", head->data );
    }

    puts( "null" );
}

int main(void) 
{
    struct node *head = NULL;

    size_t n = insert( &head );

    printf( "There are %zu nodes in the list. They are\n", n );

    display( head );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
how many numbers: 5
enter the number: 1
enter the number: 2
enter the number: 3
enter the number: 4
enter the number: 5
There are 5 nodes in the list. They are
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> null
```

Comment: I'm sorry but  I still don't understand can you please elaborate.

Comment: Like ,why is  the loop is not running twice even after i removed return statement

Comment: @Ayu91 Initially the poinetr last is equal to NULL because *ref was also equal to NULL. So if you will remove the return statement the program will have undefined behavior due to using this expression ;ast->next that is equivalent to NULL->next.